# MAMP phpmyadmin keep getting error "partitioning not defined"

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

In phpmyadmin for my MAMP I keep getting the error `"partitioning not defined"`

If I try to use the phpmyadmin interface to, for example, just simply delete a row, I check the box and hit delete and I'll get an error saying

`DELETE FROM Users WHERE LIMIT 1`

Anyone know what can be causing this? My tables do have primary keys and indexes.